# Creating Singletons - How are the instances saved

Tags: python, syntax, singleton, decorator, local-variables

When I was learning about how to create singletons in Python, most of us first come across this kind of decorator:

```
def singleton(class_):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in instances:
            instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[class_]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    pass
```

While the way this decorator works is quite intuitive, what makes me wonder is how, when we create a second object in "MyClass", this decorator checks that one has already been created.

In the definition of "singleton", Python checks the "instances" dictionary. However, it is a local variable: shouldn't it get destroyed when the function has operated? Therefore, shouldn't the `if class_ not in instances` condition always be True?

Since I know this syntax works I have been using it as is, but it makes me feel that I still don't fully understand local variables yet.

Comment: `instances` is local inside `singleton`, but is in `getinstance`'s *closure*, so there is still a reference to the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so there is still a reference to {instances} because {singleton} is still "open" ?

Answer (score 0):

`getinstance` is a *closure* over both `instances` and `class_`. What happens is that `MyClass` is not a reference to a `class` object, but to the function `getinstance`. That function retains references to the `dict` referenced by `instances` and the class referenced by `class_` after those two names go out of scope. You can see this for yourself:

```
>>> type(MyClass)
<class 'function'>
>>> MyClass.__closure__[0]
<cell at 0x107877d38: type object at 0x7fe0dcc264c8>
>>> MyClass.__closure__[1]
<cell at 0x107877d68: dict object at 0x107843ab0>
```

The first element of the `__closure__` tuple is a refernce to the original class; the second element is a reference to the instance cache.